# SQLite .NET Insert ExecuteNonQuery Returns 1

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE main.LogRecord (
Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL ,
TimeStamp DATETIME NOT NULL ,
Type TEXT NOT NULL ,
Severity TEXT NOT NULL ,
Message TEXT NOT NULL ,
Origin TEXT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO LogRecord
(TimeStamp, Type, Severity, Message, Origins) VALUES
(@timestamp, @type, @severity, @message, @origin)
```

C# Pseudo-ish Code:

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(INSERT_COMMAND_TEXT);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", object.value);
command.Connect = connectVar;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When `ExecuteNonQuery()` runs, the value `1` is returned which according to SqliteOrg means:

> *SQL error or missing database*

Except, no exception is thrown AND the data is inserted correctly.

Is there way to get the `LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE` using `System.Data.SQLite`? I've only come across ways to get the last error message for non .net APIs.

When I incorrectly insert to a column that does not exists the same error code (1) is returned BUT this time an exception is thrown with the last error message.

So if the insert is working, why is 1 being returned? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I also tried not sending the `TimeStamp DateTime` in case it was a date formatting issue but the same situation occurs.

Edit: Turns out 1 is the # of rows affected and it's all in the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Where are you getting the return value?  You could always `try catch` the exception.

Comment: I did not copy my working code verbatim - but the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reread your docs. I believe ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected or *-1* on an error.

Comment: My tired eyes missed that, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Stored procedures always return -1 - even on success.

Comment: For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure about the return value?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery.aspx

For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1.

Comment: I think its saying "Yep, I inserted '1' new row.  Congrats!"

Comment: My tired eyes missed that, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of these as the answer, so it doesn't continue to be answered.

Comment: I've "been there" on being tired!  About 1/4 of my questions on StackOF are "tired" questions........

Comment: Thanks granadaCoder, accepted Dale M's answer since he was 60 seconds faster. Have a wonderful rest of your day :)

Comment: Ok.  But that 60 seconds was me giving you an reference URL !  (No worries)

Comment: I didn't know I was allowed to take other metrics into account ;) Much appreciated :D